# What does a blue/white arrow on an app icon in app manager mean?

Tags: app-icons, application-manager

The icon in application manager for one of the applications had a blue and white arrow overlaid on it for a while. Approximately the same time the app's icon disappeared from the home screen (pressing "apps" grid symbol for the alphabetical list of apps) and I could only start the app via Google Play Store when I was online. The app's shortcut I had created disappeared with it. (Android Kit-Kat, Galaxy Note 3)

I have only seen this arrow on the icon for the app TripAdvisor.

After a while the icon on the home screen reappeared and the arrow disappeared without me doing anything I can imagine affected the situation. (I could be wrong here, though.) A little before the problem (not being able to start the app since there was no icon for it) disappeared, I had just tried at random to clear cache, force stop and disable updates. Also restarting device, of course. Re-enabling updates made the app reinstall but the problem persisted a while longer.

It is not possible to uninstall this app, you can only disable updates. (But it has been downloaded and appears among downloaded apps in the app manager. It was not included with the phone. )

The app has not (cannot) be put on the external card. It has not been disabled.

I have previously had occasional problems with apps disappearing from the alphabetical grid/list. They're still installed and visible in app manager, but cannot be started otherwise than from Google Play Store when online. If I find out the meaning of this arrow maybe I can solve such problems.

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/320xq90/r/746/wA7K0J.jpg]

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/320xq90/r/538/qWJ8To.jpg]